# Postgres FDW not compiling in Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, cgo, postgres-fdw, steampipe

I am trying to build the [`steampipe-postgres-fdw`](https://github.com/turbot/steampipe-postgres-fdw) project in a **Linux**.

The FDW is a `golang` module which compiles to a `*.a` using `-buildmode=c-archive`. The generated `.a` file is about `393 MB`.

The FDW `Makefile` looks like:

```
MODULE_big = steampipe_postgres_fdw
OBJS = [list of object files]

SHLIB_LINK = steampipe_postgres_fdw.a

EXTENSION = steampipe_postgres_fdw
DATA = steampipe_postgres_fdw--1.0.sql

REGRESS = steampipe_postgres-fdw

EXTRA_CLEAN = steampipe_postgres_fdw.a fdw.h

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
SERVER_LIB = $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --includedir-server)
INTERNAL_LIB = $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --includedir)/internal

PG_CFLAGS = -I${SERVER_LIB} -I${INTERNAL_LIB} -g

include $(PGXS)
```

Issue is that whenever I try to `make`, it spits out errors like: (similar for `amd64`)

```
/usr/bin/ld: steampipe_postgres_fdw.a(go.o): relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `type:string' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: DWARF error: line info data is bigger (0x65f0639) than the space remaining in the section (0xe86ef9)
/usr/bin/ld: DWARF error: line info data is bigger (0x66400c8) than the space remaining in the section (0xe86cbd)
...
/usr/bin/ld: steampipe_postgres_fdw.a(go.o): relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `encoding/json.stateError·f' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
go.go:(.text+0x13ade0): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
/usr/bin/ld: steampipe_postgres_fdw.a(go.o): relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `type:T9dlNKsN' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
go.go:(.text+0x13adfc): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
```

This is specific to `linux`. Builds just fine in `darwin` systems (`M1` and `Intel`)

What am I missing here?

> Not sure if this is relevant, but when the `.a` file is smaller (`~100MB`), it builds just fine.

> I have pushed a minimum reproducible code at https://github.com/turbot/steampipe-postgres-fdw/tree/debug_trivy

Comment: For a good question here, extract and provide a [mcve]. However, this looks like you're not programming but trying to compile some existing software, so also consider checking the bugtracking system for that software.

Comment: What versions of Postgres are you building against in the Linux case  vs the Darwin case?

Comment: I am building against pg14